# Последовательное выполнение функций с математическими расчетами JS

Tags: javascript, функции

Всем привет, никак не получается придумать алгоритм при котором будет последовательно выполняться n функций. Есть массив(двухмерный), к которому нужно применить все функции из другого массива.

Детали: имеем матрицу с которой возможно произвести следующие действия(транспонирование, перестановка строк, перестановка столбцов, перестановка областей), количество действий к примеру 10, так вот из за асинхронности, функции выполняются сразу и матрица ломается, а нужно по завершению каждого действия начать новое

```
var useNetwork = [] //матрица со стороной 9х9
var fL = [
        function(){
                    //transponding
            if(debug)
            console.log('transponding start');
            for(i=0;i<9;i++){
                for(j=0;j<9;j++){
                    useNetwork[j][i] = useNetwork[i][j];
                }
            }

            if(debug)
            console.log('transponding end');

        },
        function(){

            console.log('second');
        },
        function(){

            console.log('third');
        },
        function(){

            console.log('fourth');
        }
    ];

for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    nameOfFunction = fL[parseInt(Math.random() * (4 - 0) + 0)];
    nameOfFunction();

}
```

в консоль кидает следующее

```
index.html:246 fourth
index.html:225 transponding start
index.html:233 transponding end
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.map` вам в помощь

Comment: и что, нельзя оператором for обойти все функции?

Comment: for  не выходит, выполняется то три то пять то одна функция.

Comment: @user3535225 - сакраментальное: "Вы чего-то не договариваете."

Comment: добавил подробности

Comment: @user3535225 - ну, начинается. Где в Вашем коде асинхронность?

Comment: @igor я бы здесь писать не стал если бы не столкнулся с этой проблемой

Comment: @user3535225 - Вы упомянули слово "асинхронность" в третьей редакции Вашего вопроса. Мы не видим Вашего кода (кроме того, который Вы поместили в вопрос) и не можем посмотреть Вам в мозг. Предположим здесь находится человек с опытом программирования на  javascript и желанием Вам помочь. Как он может воспроизвести Вашу "проблему" (кстати, в чем она заключается?) и предложить решение?

Comment: можно например передавать в каждую функцию callback, или нельзя?

Comment: @Igor помимо асинхронности я описал проблему, применение перестановок к матрице, каждая перестановка - описана функцией, хранятся в массиве, первым циклом я генерирую другой массив в котором располагаю их в рандомном порядке n раз, а потом пробегаю по массиву, запускаю эти функции и хрен!

Comment: @user3535225 Вы молодец! С каждой Вашей фразой ситуация все более проясняется. Остается только надеяться, что она совсем прояснится до того, как мне надоест задавать Вам наводящие вопросы. Настоятельно рекомендую начать с простого и вводить усложнения пошагово.

Comment: @user3535225 "Королева в восхищении!" Теперь оказывается сюда еще и `random` замешан. Что-нибудь еще? Давайте уж сразу.

Comment: @igo random нужен только для того чтоб в случайном порядке последовательности применяемых функций применить, он роли не играет.

Comment: @user3535225 Ну так уберите его.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») **должны включать** желаемое поведение, **конкретную проблему** или ошибку и **минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. Как создать [mcve].

Comment: мне кажется у вас ложное ощущение, что функции могут выполняться одновременно

Answer (score 1):

Я тут взял с полки мое "наливное яблочко на серебряном блюдечке" и посмотрел, что там показывают по образовательному каналу. Держу пари, что Ваш код заработает, когда Вы добавите во всех Ваших циклах `var` перед счетчиком.

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
  ...
}
```

Comment: увы, в коде вар присутствует, просто торопился когда добавлял сюда и совершил помарку.

Comment: @user3535225 Вы издеваетесь?

Comment: ни коим образом, вместо усмешек и общеизвестных цитат, наверное лучше помочь) если это ваша цель